# dynamic UI file with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using a dynamic UI file and importing it to my Python code, there are some option I want to set on the QlineEdit like setEchoMode()

```
self.Password = self.password.text()
```

I want to mask this and show only **

any help ?

Comment: Please show how you are loading the UI dynamically and also the name of the password widget in Qt designer

Comment: UI_File, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'work.ui'))
class MainAPP(QTabWidget, UI_File):                                                        
   def __init__(self, parent=None):                                       
       self.os_pass = self.ospassword.text()

Comment: Have you tried placing the below solution (but using the correct widget name (`self.ospassword.setEchoMode(...)`) in the `__init__` method?

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for setEchoMode for LineEdit. This works for PyQt4.

```
self.lineEdit_password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
```